# How to initiaze a typedef struct pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct, typedef

I need to initialize a typedef struct pointer

in header file,

```
typedef struct {
    DWORD RxBuf[4];             
    DWORD Tr0c;                 
} t, *p_t;
```

In the cpp file,

```
static p_t p1
    = {
    {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00},  
    0               
};
```

Comment: You've declared `p1` as a pointer, so the initialization would need to be a pointer.

Comment: You need something for your pointer to point *to*.  You have given an initializer for that thing, not for a *pointer* to that thing.

Comment: What about `memset(g_pT, 0, sizeof(t));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, I believe you want to do:

```
static t tNull
    = {
    {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00},  
    0               
};

static p_t p1 = &tNull;
```

Comment: @RaydelMiranda: Not if you want this pointer type to point to it. (Why you'd want to define this pointer type is another matter, but that's what the OP is asking for.)

Answer (score 1):

`p_t` is a pointer, therefore you have to point it to a valid object of type `t`.

You can make the object and point to it:

```
t var = { { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 } , 5  } ;
p_t pointer = &var ;
```

Or use a compound literal:

```
p_t pointer = &( t ){ { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 } , 5  } ;
```